# Log4j doesn't save all logs to file

Tags: java, logging, gradle, spring-boot, log4j

I have a problem. I want to save ALL logs to file. When I'm runing my spring-boot application, I have this in console:

```
...
2017-03-09 20:12:26.985  INFO 379180 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.jetty.ContextHandler.application     : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-03-09 20:12:26.988  INFO 379180 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-03-09 20:12:27.023  INFO 379180 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 33 ms
...
```

etc. And I want to have all this also in file. Saving to file works ok. I used `logger.info()` to test it and I have `logfile.log` with this inside:

```
2017-03-09 20:18:11,587  INFO [restartedMain] - com.xyz.Application.main 17 - test1
```

and nothing more. Here is my class:

```
public class Application {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Application.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        log.info("test1");
    }
}
```

And here is my `log4j.properties`:

```
# TRACE < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, toFile

#DailyRollingFile
log4j.appender.toFile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.toFile.Append=true
log4j.appender.toFile.File=./log/logfile.log
log4j.appender.toFile.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
log4j.appender.toFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.toFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%t] - %c.%M %L - %m%n
```

What I'm doing wrong? Somebody have maybe any idea?

Comment: If your `log4j.properties` file is configured to send everything to appender  `toFile`, and nothing to the console, and you're still getting logging messages in the console, then those logging messages are not generated by Log4j.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found solution. I hade to add to `build.gradle` this:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: "commons-logging", module: "commons-logging"
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
    exclude module: "logback-classic"
}
```

Now I have all logs in file.